# Bootstrap Form, avoid inputs from moving down when a jquery.validation.js notification is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

So i have a form with bootstrap inputs, im using the jquery.validation.js library, so, its working correctly, the thing is that when an error notificacion is displayed the input fields and labels moves downwoards. Example:

here is the form on his normal state:

[image]

here is the form when it displays those messages, as you can see the input fields and labels move downwoards.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I see where you mean?  Are the error messages supposed to be directly underneath the inputs?

Comment: yes, they are supposed to be underneth them

Comment: I assume the reason they are all being pushed down is because more elements are being inserted into the DOM when an error message displays.  It's just normal flow.

Comment: is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see the labels or inputs moving down from the screenshots. But anyways, why don't you wrap a div or a span below the input field and let it take fixed amount of space. And then have the notification shown there without the DOM having to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a row for each input, for example:

```
<div class="row col-md-12"> 

         <div class="col-md-4">  
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <label for="numero">Número de Calle </label> 
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" placeholder="Número de calle" v-model="documento.rev_nrocalle" v-validate:numero="{required: true, maxlength: 4 }" autocomplete="off" required>
                          <small class="help-block" style="">  <span class="animated" transition="fade"  v-show="$validaciones.numero.required && formIsInvalid"><strong>Introducir un número de calle válido </strong></span></small>
                        </div> 
                       
                    </div> 
</div>
```

this is the way , to avoid the moving down in my case im using vue.js to validate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like this and was able to fix it by changing the the height of the paragraph element inside my div containing the "is required" statement and also changing the margin of my div, so look and see if either those two things or the padding are what is affecting it and change it.